# Как сделать маску телефона в инпуте, чтобы она отображалась постоянно, а не только при нажатие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать маску телефона в инпуте, чтобы она отображалась постоянно, а не только при нажатие?Буду рад любой помощи.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#feedTel").mask("8(999) 999-9999",{autoclear: false});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script> 
<input id="feedTel">
```

Comment: есть у input штука такая - placeholder="8(999) 999-9999"

Comment: Евгений Ли, спасибо, так и поступил)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить опцию `{autoclear: false}`, т.е.

```
$("#feedTel").mask("8(999) 999-9999",{autoclear: false})
```

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, спасибо за помощь, но вариант не помогает. Я в пример кода добавил-что то не работает